# Remove string from each item on array using VB

Tags: vbscript

Basically I've an array that looks like this

```
array = ("Hello_123","Hello_234","Hello_345")
```

I would like to remove the word "Hello_" from the array so that the result would become

```
array = ("123","234","345")
```

Any idea how can I do that please?

Comment: Loop through the array and update the values using `Replace()`.

Comment: Are you programming in VB or VBScript? They're not the same thing. The line `array = ("Hello_123","Hello_234","Hello_345")` doesn't work in VBScript. It should be something like `MyArray = Array("Hello_123","Hello_234","Hello_345")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by @user692942, loop through the array and update the values using `Replace()` like this:

```
MyArray = Array("Hello_123","Hello_234","Hello_345")
For i = 0 to UBound(MyArray)
  MyArray(i) = Replace(MyArray(i),"Hello_","")
Next
```